# Determining main verb of a sentence which match with subject + verb + to + verb pattern

Tags: verbs, sentence, infinitives, sentence-patterns, syntactic-analysis

If I have sentences

> - Member is allowed to change himself back
> - I want to go to school
> - He needs to stop

What are the predicate of these sentences? Are they **allowed - want - need**, or **change - go - stop**?
What do we call this **subject + verb + to + verb** pattern?

Thanks,

### Edit:

What I really want to know is the **main verb** of sentences which match with **subject + verb + to + verb** pattern. Based on three sample sentences above, we can say that the main verb are second verb, i.e. verb after **to**.
Do this assumption apply to all sentences which match with pattern above?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Please check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(grammar))

Comment: Is it wrong if this is a homework?

Comment: It depends on your definition of 'main verb'. The simple predicate of a clause has to be a finite verb. So the simple predicates of your sentences are 'is allowed', 'need' and 'want'.

Comment: If it is, there is a Homework tag so people know that they are helping you with homework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the main verb in an English sentence, first find all the [Verb Phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf). Each one defines a clause, because only clauses have Verb Phrases.

The main Verb Phrase of the whole Sentence is the Verb Phrase that all the other clauses modify; this makes the clause containing it the Main Clause. So the main verb in the Main Clause in a sentence is the main verb of that sentence.

In each Verb Phrase, the main verb is the **last** verb; all the other verbs in that Verb Phrase can be ignored. The rule is then that the last verb in the Verb Phrase of the main Clause is the main verb of the sentence.

In the sentences presented,

1. *Member is allowed to change himself back*
2. *I want to go to school*
3. *He needs to stop*

In (1), *is allowed* and *to change himself back* are the verb phrases, and since the second one is the object of the first, that makes the first one the main verb phrase, and the main verb in it is ***is***. (The real predicate in this sentence is actually *allowed*, but that's a predicate adjective, not a verb.)

In (2) *want* and *to go to school* are the VPs, and the second modifies the first again, so the main verb is ***want***.

In (3) *needs* and *to stop*, same story. Main verb, ***needs***.

Answer (score 2):

In traditional grammar clauses are divided into two main parts: **subject** (what the clause is about) and **predicate** (information about the subject). The predicate is everything that remains when the subject is removed. In the simple sentences listed (which are single independent clauses), the subjects are: *member, I, he*. The predicate in each case is the rest of the sentence: '*is not allowed to change himself back*', '*want to go to school*', '*need to stop*'.

The problem with this traditional definition of the subject as being 'what the clause is about' is that it doesn't apply in cases such as "It is raining". Modern grammars use different terms to define the constituent parts of clauses.

Comment: Yes -- or put another way, if you're struggling to decide what is the "subject" and what is the "predicate", this is possibly God's way of telling you you've outgrown the usefulness of such an analysis... :)

Answer (score 0):

The first example is incomprehensible but if the second example illustrates the pattern you’re concerned about, then, as Shoe has said, the whole of the sentence following *I* is the Predicate. That, however, doesn’t take us very far. The structure of the clause is Subject-Verb-Object. The Subject is realised by the Noun Phrase *I*, the Verb by the Verb Phrase *want* and the Object by the Verb Phrase *to go to school*. The ‘main verb’ is *want*.